# Linux: How can I view a file's attributes which I set using `chattr`?

Tags: linux, chattr

I have a file, which I wanted to protect from accidental deletion, so I've ran:

```
chattr +i filename
```

Now my question is, once I've changed a file attributes, where can I see the newly set attributes?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You want

```
lsattr filename
```

See [`man lsattr`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/lsattr.1.html).